# Filter out questions I've already voted to close from the Triage queue

Tags: bug, review, triage

About five minutes ago, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27597630/filter-price-range-php-mysql) on Stack Overflow, and voted to close it. Two minutes later, it popped up in my Triage queue. When clicking "unsalvagable", I only got an option to flag it, as I've already voted to close beforehand.

Now, I think it's a bad question, but not a flag-worthy bad question, so I was left with no option but to click "should be improved", which, IMHO, is wrong.

Can we prevent questions that a user already voted to close from appeaing in his Triage queue? Ideally, actually, we'd want to prevent questions with **any** activity from a user in his Triage queue. Any action on a question implicitly implies the user's opinion on this question, and there's no point for him to triage it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your option in this case is to hit the Skip button...

[image]

but I agree that it would be nice if questions you already hit with a flag or vote should be filtered out beforehand.